# Error saving psql history file

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

My current `psql` version is 10.1, 
but when I type `\q` to save the history it shows:

> postgres=# \q could not save history to file "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/.psql_history": No such file or directory

But I am using **Postgres 10.1**, how to fix this?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68705/could-not-save-history-to-file-var-lib-postgresql-psql-history-no-such-file Check this bro :)

Comment: What do you get for `echo $HOME` in a shell as user `postgres`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How psql determines the path of the history file is [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) as:

> **HISTFILE**
>
> The file name that will be used to store the history list. If unset, the file name is taken from the PSQL_HISTORY environment
>   variable. If that is not set either, the default is ~/.psql_history,
>   or %APPDATA%\postgresql\psql_history on Windows

You must be aware that`psql` does not use `HOME` to figure out the home directory represented by the tidle character, it uses `/etc/passwd`.

So presumably in the question `psql` is launched by the `postgres` user, and when this user was created, it was to install PostgreSQL 9.3 on this machine, and it was not changed afterwards when `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/` got deleted, so the entry in `/etc/passwd` still points to that non-existing directory.

[This answer on DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83822/7119)  give the shell command to fix that:

```
sudo usermod --home '/path/to/database' postgres
```

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I disagree with that characterization. This question is about `psql` which has its own tag on S.O. with 460+ followers and 1,6k questions and which to me falls into the _software tools commonly used by programmers_ category mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm surprised there's that many questions for something that's a database query tool, and not a programming tool.  Perhaps more than a few are about using `psql` from within programs?  Either way, I guess there's no point in arguing with a crowd, no matter how wrong they are...